# Bongo Back Ends

Tags: bongo

The bongo music player has been the coolest find yet in my on going discovery of the many capabilities of Emacs. My only problem is that it can't seem to 1. open or 2. play any of my .flac files. I have downloaded `vlc` and `mpv`. All I know to do at this point is to open `M-x customize-group RET bongo`, and then open `Bongo Enabled Backends`. Here I check mark either one and set for future sessions. At this point, I can open a bongo buffer and load .flac files. 1. complete. However, when I try to play one of these juicy .flac files, I get a `Searching for program: No such file or directory exists`, (here we see `vlc` or `mpv`, depending on which I checked in the bongo enabled backends step above)".

I have since tried this bit of code, keeping with using mpv instead of vlc

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```

Now I get an error that says, `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

I edited this post to hopefully meet the requirements better so it isnt deleted. If there is anything further I can do, please let me know. Thanks!

This is the tracing I get in the error.

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  make-process(:name "bongo-mpv" :buffer nil :command ("mpv" nil "/var/folders/l8/vzz9lqbs17s745cykjsg7wr80000gn/T/bongo-mpv.socket" "--no-audio-display" "/Volumes/MEdia/newb/Animals as Leaders/Animals as Leaders/07 The Price of Everything and the Value of Nothing.flac"))
  apply(make-process (:name "bongo-mpv" :buffer nil :command ("mpv" nil "/var/folders/l8/vzz9lqbs17s745cykjsg7wr80000gn/T/bongo-mpv.socket" "--no-audio-display" "/Volumes/MEdia/newb/Animals as Leaders/Animals as Leaders/07 The Price of Everything and the Value of Nothing.flac")))
  start-process("bongo-mpv" nil "mpv" nil "/var/folders/l8/vzz9lqbs17s745cykjsg7wr80000gn/T/bongo-mpv.socket" "--no-audio-display" "/Volumes/MEdia/newb/Animals as Leaders/Animals as Leaders/07 The Price of Everything and the Value of Nothing.flac")
  apply(start-process "bongo-mpv" nil "mpv" (nil "/var/folders/l8/vzz9lqbs17s745cykjsg7wr80000gn/T/bongo-mpv.socket" "--no-audio-display" "/Volumes/MEdia/newb/Animals as Leaders/Animals as Leaders/07 The Price of Everything and the Value of Nothing.flac"))
  bongo-start-mpv-player("/Volumes/MEdia/newb/Animals as Leaders/Animals as Leaders/07 The Price of Everything and the Value of Nothing.flac" nil)
  bongo-play-file("/Volumes/MEdia/newb/Animals as Leaders/Animals as Leaders/07 The Price of Everything and the Value of Nothing.flac" nil)
  bongo-play-line(1007)
  bongo-play-lines(nil)
  bongo-dwim()
  bongo-mouse-dwim((mouse-2 (# 817 (135 . 173) 231234011 nil 817 (14 . 10) nil (7 . 13) (8 . 16))))
  funcall-interactively(bongo-mouse-dwim (mouse-2 (# 817 (135 . 173) 231234011 nil 817 (14 . 10) nil (7 . 13) (8 . 16))))
  call-interactively(bongo-mouse-dwim nil nil)
  command-execute(bongo-mouse-dwim)

Comment: The question should stand alone. Please move/copy all relevant information into the question. Otherwise it risks deletion.

Comment: Please put the actual backtrace here instead of hiding it in one of those annoying pastebins that may disappear.